# Подключение облачного хранилища к сайту

Tags: php, облачное-хранилище

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как подключить облачное хранилище к сайту? Необходимо закачивать файлы в облако через админку и скачивать файлы пользователем. Интересует техническая сторона вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Я интегрировал админку кастомного компонента Joomla 1.5 с Amazon S3: загружают картинки в админку, и они дублируются в облако, откуда и раздаются посетителям сайта и читателям email рассылки.

В реализации нет ничего сложного. Амазоны предлагают свой SDK под PHP (и под другие языки тоже есть), с помощью которого любой функционал их сервисов удобно рулится.

Кроме того, многие плагины умеют работать с "облачными" сервисами, в т.ч. того же Амазона. Например планины кэширования под WordPress умеют заливать статику на S3.